# Kohana 2 database insert - insert id is returned but it is protected?

Tags: php, mysql, kohana

So this code:

```
 $db = Database::instance();
 $result = $db->query("insert into parser_log (sent)
                       values (".sizeof($jobs).")");
```

returns an object with the insert id, but when I try to access it:

```
 Fatal error: Cannot access protected property Mysql_Result::$insert_id
```

What is up with that? Must I run a separate query to get the id? seems like a waste since the id is right there.

Answer (score 1):

1. your code is invalid, you have to pass at least 2 arguments to the `query` method:

   $db->query(Database::INSERT, 'insert into ...');
2. `query` method returns an array with last insert id and count of affected rows
3. You have not specified the line that throws such error